Signal recovery limits, magnetic
This question is about signal recovery. I am interested in what is the best that has been done so far, in the case of a signal of known form and which is not simply a sine wave, and what might in principle be possible.
The situation I have in mind is where one wants to distinguish a signal from nothing, or tell two signals apart, both of whose forms are known. It might, for example, be two different melodies (twinkle twinkle little star vs happy birthday or similar) encoded by frequency modulation or by some digital method operating in the time/frequency domain. The point being that if one knows what signals one is looking for, there are further possibilities for signal recovery beyond mere filtering and integration. (I think the LIGO observatory uses this fact in extracting gravitational wave signals, for example). To make the question specific, I would like to propose the signal is in the magnetic field, the available integration time (including processing by a neural network or similar) is 10 seconds, and the noise is whatever is typical in ordinary environments on Earth. Error correction coding/decoding is allowed in the signal preparation and recovery. My question is, roughly what is feasible? I know that picotesla field changes are seen with good SN ratio in magnetocardiography, on timescales of order milliseconds.
So I think that in 10 seconds and a known signal form one could probably detect a signal whose amplitude was $10^{-15}\,$T. From a helpful answer to (my own) similar question here What's the smallest signal to noise ratio for which a signal has been extracted?
I learned that WSPR (ham radio protocol) "is good enough to permit error-free radio communication between any two points on earth on much less than one watt of radiated power, as long as ionospheric bounce conditions prevail." By estimating the energy density at the detector in this case, I find the field amplitude here is very roughly of order $10^{-14}\,$T.
But I suspect the real limit could be a lot lower still. That is my question: what might the limit be? Even a very rough estimate would be helpful.

"The point being that if one knows what signals one is looking for, there are further possibilities for signal recovery beyond mere filtering and integration." This is only true if the noise is not thermal (Gaussian). If in fact the interference process is Gaussian distributed AND the signal to be detected is known then there is nothing better then a matched filter = correlator/integrator, see, and since there is always some thermal noise the SNR performance of the matched filter is a lower bound to the best actual that cannot be beat.
